# MongoDB Spring Data how can I aggregate count from multiple fields?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework

Let's assume that there are some data like this:

```
{
"orderId": 1,
    "manager" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "UserId1"
        }
    ],
    "employee" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "UserId3"
        }
    ]
}

{
"orderId": 2,
    "manager" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "UserId1"
        }
    ],
    "employee" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "UserId2"
        }
    ]
}

{
"orderId": 3,
    "manager" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "UserId1"
        }
    ],
    "employee" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "UserId2"
        }
    ]
}
```

The result should be:

```
{  
   "Agg":[  
      {  
         "userId":"UserId1",
         "total":3
      },
      {  
         "userId":"UserId2",
         "total":2
      },
      {  
         "userId":"UserId3",
         "total":1
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to get all aggregated count of userId engaged in some process. I need to group by userId from "employee" and "manager" objects and sum them. Only what I can dois group by userId from one list:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
   match(Criteria.where("project").is("project")),
   unwind("manager"),
   group("manager.userId").count().as("total"),
   project("total").and("userId").previousOperation(),
   sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "total")
);
```

How can I aggregate count from "manager" and "employee" fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$concatArrays`.

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
   match(Criteria.where("project").is(project)),
   project("employee", "manager"),         
   project().and("manager").concatArrays("employee").as("merged"),
   unwind("merged"),
   group("merged.userId").count().as("total"),
   project("total").and("userId").previousOperation(),
   sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "total")
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
 "$group' : { 
  '_id' : '$id', 
  'totalManager' : { '$sum' : '$manager.total' },
  'totalemployee' : { '$sum' : '$employee.total' }
}  }
 { "$project" : {
  'totalManager' : '$totalManager',
  'totalemployee' : '$totalemployee',
  'totalSum' : { '$add' : [ '$totalManager', '$totalemployee' ] },
 }
```